How to run cypress scripts headed but without GUI runner
I want to run the scripts in headed mode without the Test Runner GUI using the command npx cypress run --headed. It's been a year since I worked with Cypress, and I remember it used to run that way, but now it behaves differently.
Tried "npx cypress run --headed"

Added in Cypress 13.0.0, there is a command line option to disable the runner UI: --no-runner-ui.

To prevent Cypress from rendering the Runner UI, use --no-runner-ui.

npx cypress run --headed --no-runner-ui should give you the expected behavior.
